# How to get lat/long of the center pixel in a raster image in R?

Tags: r, raster, r-raster

I want to extract the Latitude and Longitude information of the pixel that is in the center of a raster image. If the raster image is not exactly square (e.g. it is not 50x50), I want to get the lat/long of approximately the center pixel. Here is some reproducible data:

```
library(raster)
r = raster(ncol=25, nrow=25, xmn=-1000, xmx=1000, ymn=-100, ymx=900, vals = 1:(25*25))
crs(r) = crs(raster())
```

Comment: If you want the center of the raster you could convert the extent to a polygon, then take the centroid. This might not give you the centroid of the center pixel, but that might be possible if you have an even number of pixels in a given raster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach to get the center of the central grid cell

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(ncol=25, nrow=25, xmn=-1000, xmx=1000, ymn=-100, ymx=900)

row <- trunc(nrow(r)/2)
col <- trunc(ncol(r)/2)
c(row, col)
#[1] 12 12
cell <- cellFromRowCol(r, row, col)
cell
#[1] 287
xyFromCell(r, cell)
#       x   y
#[1,] -80 440
```

Another way could be to get the center of the raster and the grid cell that it falls in

```
x <- xmin(r) + (xmax(r) - xmin(r))/2
y <- ymin(r) + (ymax(r) - ymin(r))/2
cell <- cellFromXY(r, cbind(x,y))
cell
#313
rowColFromCell(r, cell)
#     row col
#[1,]  13  13
xyFromCell(r, cell)
#     x   y
#[1,] 0 400
```

The difference here is because the number or rows and columns is even, so you can take `c(12, 12)` or `c(13, 13)` or some other variation of 12 and 13.

Comment: Great approach! Would you also please show how you would take lat/long information as well?

Comment: I do not understand that question. The above using lon/lat (even if referred to by x and y)

Answer (score 1):

Building on your code and my comment above, here is an example. Obviously, this would not help your situation for an irregular shaped raster.

```
library(raster)
library(sf)
r = raster(ncol=25, nrow=25, xmn=-1000, xmx=1000, ymn=-100, ymx=900, vals = 1:(25*25))
crs(r) = crs(raster())

#convert extent of raster to poly
poly<-st_as_sfc(st_bbox(raster(r))) 
class(poly)
plot(r)
plot(st_geometry(poly), border="red", add=TRUE)

#get centroid
cent<-st_centroid(poly)
plot(st_geometry(cent), add=TRUE)
```

Comment: it is a good approach when the raster image dimensions are even numbers. How would you approach the problem if the raster image was, say `21x50` or something like that?